# Dealing with pygmy superpigs in Angry Birds Epic?

Tags: angry-birds-epic

I have localized version of Angry Birds Epic, so sorry if my names for things don't match, loosely translating.

Game says pretty explicitly about finding specific combinations of birds for fights. I got basics worked out more or less (almost always need healer, sometimes heavy hitters work better, don't waste effects on immune enemies, etc), but having a lot of trouble with combination for damn **super overpowered pygmy pigs** (they are clearly pinnacle of pig evolution I've seen so far).

As a whole this pig tribe has got following abilities:

- sturdy (easily multiple 500+ HP on screen)
- hard hitting (bunch of them deal damage very fast and boost with pepper)
- get reinforcements (summoners who get in more summoners? yikes)
- larger pigs come in single-target **and** multi-target versions
- got healers that are just ridiculous (restore 150+HP every turn for 3 turns, wat?)

I am level 9, coming to "cliffs" area (left of map after sea, then going up), with most recipes from stores bought/crafted and all bird classes so far bought (except one for black bird that just opened up).

What had I tried:

- white healer bird is simply a must, using with druid class since first one seemed less efficient at healing
- red bird with samurai defense makes survival easier, but locks it on defense completely, without making any considerable damage
- yellow bird with area poision/heal seems useful against crowds, but it simply doesn't have HP to take a larger pig hit
- black bird seems a little inflexible since it does little, but hit hard
- blue bird with poison/retarget is a monster... however the only reliable dispel is *another* class of it :(

Trying to focus on defense leaves me without sufficient damage dealing. Trying to hit hard isn't fast enough to prevent me from getting wiped out.

Birds must prevail! How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so from more experimentation and looking up walkthrough videos around here is what I ended up with that left me finally pass pygmy canyon part and served me well through all next reef part.

## Write-offs

### Red

Boosts defense greatly, but gets tied up in it (and ties up some other bird redirecting), which completely compromises damage. In other words you just die slower.

### Yellow

Does a lot of nifty things, but staying alive is sadly not one of them.

## The Team

### White

- class — druid for great heal and multi-turn thorns (rarely first class when need to hit hard and *really* fast
- weapon — one with dispel, because that's about only only dispel that can be crammed in, without dedicating whole bird to it
- strategy — open with thorns, stay on heal, when healed — repeat thorns. Chili super heal, only when in very serious trouble.

### Black

- class — the one with multi-attack and debuff (rarely one with strong attack for enemies who are immune to low damage)
- weapon — one with chain, which combines with multi for three checks and generates steady trickle of overflow damage
- strategy — hit hard, don't forget chili for massive area attack

### Blue

- class — poison! the total damage that starts going around gets ridiculously high
- weapon — whatever with best damage
- strategy — spread poison around, occasionally redirect helps to draw fire from chewed up bird. Chili attack for some damage **and** stun **and** debuff, makes all the difference against larger pigs.

When stuck don't forget to go buy & craft latest recipes, as well as grind up a level if close.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the counter attack combination for pygmy pigs.  This works great against any pig that does multiple attacks.

Red - knight.  Shields himself and attacks occasionally.

Yellow - mage. Shock shield is awesome.

Blue - rogue. Force the enemies to all attack red and to spread dots around

Against the big pig boss I swap out yellow for druid Matilda and rely on dots and chili peppers on red to take it down.

The goal is to always focus damage on red while he has the shield on and reflect damage back to the pigs.

If you are willing to use items to heal you won't need Matilda

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting.  Typed this on my phone

Comment: What is "dots"? Need to revisit shock shield, but R-Y-B or R-W-B either doesn't work for me really on final pygmy stage with three waves (I barely managed to pass it once yesterday with W-Bl-B heavy hitting set and a lot of luck).

Comment: @rarst dot=damage over time.  Shock shield is the key for pygmys since they attack multiple times and take tons of damage from it.  Usually all it takes is one round of shock shield/return damage from lure and they are almost dead